# Minor adjustment to badge description

Tags: discussion, badges

Shouldn't the description of the gold badge 'Electorate'

> Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

be

> Vote on 600 questions and answers* and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

?

Logically, the first description is unnecessarily explicit.

<sup>(* Preferably with a more concise form of "questions and answers".)</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that description is correct. You need to vote at least 600 times on questions, and for your votes on questions to be at least 25% of your total votes.

Comment: Wait, "you need votes", or "you need to vote on"? In order to get the badge you need to vote 600 times yourself, of which (>)25% on questions, and (<)75% *can* be on answers, right?

Comment: You need to vote 600 times specifically on questions. That's why the decription mentions "on questions".

Comment: Sure. But then my question still stands: why explicate that at least 25% of those votes on questions should be votes on questions? (I'm beginning to get the idea I'm missing something obvious here..)

Comment: Because there are two separate requirements. One is for you to have voted on questions at least 600 times. The second is for your votes on questions to be at least 25% of your total votes (on questions and answers).

Comment: So the 600 votes make up the 25%?

Comment: At least 25%, yes. Could be 100% if all your votes are on qestions.

Comment: Okay, thanks for bearing with me! Still, wouldn't a better description be something like "Vote 600 times on questions, which makes up at least 25% of all your votes"? Hmm, I think my problem lies with the phrasing "total votes", which I interpreted as being the total of those 600 votes - as a self-contained description. Well, I can imagine being the only one tripping over this, so, nevermind..