# What does the "25% vote on questions" mean on the "Electorate" badge?

Tags: support, badges, user-profile, recent-activity

If you read my [profile,](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/267846/loan-2314?tab=profile) and see my [activity,](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/267846/loan-2314?tab=topactivity) I am trying to earn the ["Electorate"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/155/electorate) badge. I have 329 votes cast and only 324 are recorded, but this isn't a bug! I just want to know what the "25%" of it means, because of the fact that only 324 votes are recorded.

---

I tried to figure it out, so I hovered my mouse onto the badge des, and it says, 98% out of 25% on questions. Is this good or bad? What does the "25%" mean?

Comment: Is the description you linked to, "Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions", not sufficient?

Comment: [Related](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14614/minor-adjustment-to-badge-description) (wherein contained lies the account of the discernment of said insignia's stipulations of yours faithfully).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've cast 329 up-/downvotes, as shown in [this widget](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/267846/loan-2314?tab=topactivity#user-panel-votes):

[image]

but for the Electorate badge only votes on *questions* count, and you only have 324 of those.

The 25% rule is comparing your votes on questions (324) to your *total* votes (329), so you have a percentage of 324/329 = 98%.